# Android - Timeout in DataOutputStream.writeUTF

Tags: android, sockets, dataoutputstream

I have an Android app that connects to a TCP Java Server. The data is written with [DataOutputStream.writeUTF](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29). I want to simulate a failing GPRS connection, so I did the following:

1. Start up the Java TCP Server
2. Connect the Android app
3. Turn-off the network of Java TCP Server
4. Write some data from the app

So, when I wrote something to the unreachable TCP Server, I didn't know if it goes with success.

My question is... Can I know if the package is really sent to TCP Server, like a timeout try?